# ¿Como seleccionar al menos un valor duplicado de mi JTable?

Tags: javascript, java, sql

Intento establecer una condición que me determine que por lo menos que he seleccionado al menos un valor duplicado en mi JTable, la información en el JTable luce de esta manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo algo de este estilo que llena el JTable

```
try {            
    Connection con = null;
    con = getConection();
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet res;
    ps = con.prepareStatement("EXEC PA_ENTREGA_A_RECEPCION " + quincena.getSelectedItem() + "," + ano.getSelectedItem());
    res = ps.executeQuery();
    Resultado.clear();
    while (res.next()) {
        Object[] resu = new Object[2];
        resu[0] = res.getString(1).trim();               
        resu[1] = false;
        Resultado.add(resu);
    }
    int arregloTam = Resultado.size();
    Object[][] data = new Object[arregloTam][2];
    for (int i = 0; i < arregloTam; i++) {
        data[i] = Resultado.get(i);
    }
    DefaultTableModel tb_model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    jTable1 = new JTable(tb_model) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
            switch (column) {
                case 0:
                    return String.class;
                case 1:                            
                    return Boolean.class;
                default:
                    return String.class;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            switch (col) {
                case 0:
                    return false;
                case 1:                           
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    };            
} catch (SQLException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Seleccione una Qna");
} catch (Throwable ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Existen Faltantes de R3");
}
```

Comment: Publica por favor algo de tu código o algo que permita que te puedan ayudar. Te recomiendo leer [ask]

Comment: Gracias @LeviArista